# ElasticSearch: do not exists on master, act as master failure?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 nodes, first node is Buzz Search 5 , and 2nd node is called Buzz Search 6. Currently Buzz Search 5 is running for a day. It has minimum_master_nodes set to 1. It does NOT have the host name for Buzz Search 6 in the list of unicast hosts.

I want to join Buzz Search 6 to it. It does have the host name of BuzzSearch 6 in list of unicast hosts in config file. It has minimum_master_nodes set to 2. When I attempt to start it, I get this error:

```
[2014-03-13 21:22:49,334][INFO ][discovery.zen ] [Buzz Search 6] master_left [[BuzzSumo Search 5][utWqLm8DRtCGXOI9vKy8vw][sdfsdfsd.net][inet[/122.19.11.152:9300]]], reason [do not exists on master, act as master failure]
[2014-03-13 21:22:49,335][DEBUG][cluster.service ] [Buzz Search 6] processing [zen-disco-master_failed ([Buzz Search 5][utWqLm8DRtCGXOI9vKy8vw][sdfsdfsd.net][inet[/122.19.11.152:9300]])]: execute
[2014-03-13 21:22:49,335][DEBUG][cluster.service ] [Buzz Search 6] processing [zen-disco-master_failed ([Buzz Search 5][utWqLm8DRtCGXOI9vKy8vw][sdfsdfsd.net][inet[/122.19.11.152:9300]])]: no change in cluster_state
[2014-03-13 21:22:58,135][DEBUG][transport.netty ] [Buzz Search 6] connected to node [[Buzz Search 6][UVX-vS3WQrKPaZoc4hv7qA][sdfsdfsd.net][inet[/122.19.11.152:9300]]]
```

What does this error mean? it's so cryptic. 
reason [do not exists on master, act as master failure]

More importantly, how can I resolve it?

Comment: Your buzz search server 6 started or not??

Comment: yes it started. I think its an error with the first node, Buzz Search 5. It is not accepting connections and not even responding to PUT update settings request

Answer (score 0):

"   processing [zen-disco-master_failed ([Buzz.       Search 5][utWqLm8DRtCGXOI9vKy8vw][sdfsdfsd.net][inet[/122.19.11.152:9300]])]: execute
[2014-03-13 21:22:49,335][DEBUG][cluster.service ]"

The above error message makes sense.. 
 There is some problems with buzz search 5.. Try to restart the buzz search 5.. And wait till d node is up and test again..

Comment: Yes, definitely a problem. do u think what the problem may be with that node? it does respond to search and index queries. I posted a different question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412792/elasticsearch-put-settings-no-response

Comment: If a node can't connect to cluster means first we need to check cluster names mentioned in every node must be identical..is it identical??

Comment: yes, they're identical. They were connected for awhile: a few hrs then disconnected